Analyzing review rating using R STM package - sample balance issue
For the online reviews datasets, one of the tasks is to investigate the difference in topic proportion (e.g., topics as positively vs. negatively commented). Because of the positively skewed J-shaped distribution of online reviews rating / unbalanced distribution of ratings, scholars tend to balance the sample size, that is, randomly select positive rating reviews (i.e., 4- and 5-point ratings) so making its number equal or similar to those of negative rating reviews (i.e., 1- and 2-point ratings). Similar to the practice of below papers:
Paper 1: What do hotel customers complain about? Text analysis using structural topic model
Paper 2: The Voice of Drug Consumers: Online Textual Review Analysis Using Structural Topic Model
The reason of removing some rating reviews to achieve balanced sample is (extracted from Paper 2):

...when using review extremities as covariates in the STM model, it is
essential to initially filter the positive and negative reviews to
balance the sample size of positive and negative reviews, which can
help us to identify topics that appear significantly more in negative
reviews than in positive ones more reliably.

Since removing samples from a dataset is always a poor practice, my question is: is it justified to remove some rating reviews to achieve balanced sample in the case of examining the difference in topic proportion in the STM model?

Can you be a little more explicit what you mean by "the unbalanced sample issue"? What is the issue you are concerned about? You may find this interesting: Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?

I would consider this a poor practice in almost all cases, one coming from not really knowing how to evaluate models. While Kolassa's link concerns "classification" problems with categorical outcomes, it isn't much of a stretch to extend that logic to distributions in general that are not uniform and artificially transforming them to uniformity by misleading the model.

@Dave, do you mean that removing reviews in the case of the positively skewed J-shaped distribution of online reviews rating dataset is a poor practice?

@StephanKolassa, simply put, "the unbalanced sample issue" in the case of the positive skewed J-shaped distribution of online reviews rating dataset is that the number of 4- and 5-rating reviews is overwhelming larger than that of 1- and 2-rating reviews.

Lying to the model about the reality of the data is probably a poor practice, yes. If that J shape is the reality of how the reviews are distributed, so be it. What problem do you see that changing the J-shape solves?

And what precisely is the issue here? You have more data of one type than of another, because that is the population you are studying. It's not like you are introducing selection bias by selecting your samples selectively. Unless, that is, you oversample... and it's precisely then that you will introduce bias. See my link above. I am absolutely with @Dave here.

Sorry for the poor presentation. I've edit the question for clarity.

Please say what problem you hope to solve by removing ratings. I have yet to see any mention of what is a problem that warrants remedy, even setting aside discussions of what would be a suitable remedy.

@StephanKolassa I was recently pointed to an unrelated Transactions of Machine Learning Research article from last month and wound up perusing the other June article titles, coming across two papers about skewed outcomes. Skimming both, they seem to take it as self-evident that the skewness if a problem, which is not so obvious to me. I am left reminded of a quote from Jurassic Park: "...scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could [fix outcome skewness] that they didn't stop to think if they should!"

Since the test sample is balanced on the target variable WOW! I didn't even see a discussion of this in the open review used by TMLR. I get the idea of balancing if you are in the position to have observed skewed data but want to make predictions in a situation where there is balance (however you wind up in such a situation), but that hardly seems like the typical use-case. This strikes me as trying to out-clever Bayes' theorem when the data do not support high likelihoods of unusual events but you wish you could predict them reliably.

The simple answer to your question is: no, you don't need to imbalance your own data by randomly eliminating values. Start by reading the discussion here: When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?. You can't really assert STM requires special considerations with this level of discussion on the general topic of machine learning. If you're not convinced, build a few toy datasets, and play with STM modeling yourself - you are unlimited in discovery once you can simulate your own data. Lastly, use your gut. Do you really believe the explanation you quoted? It sounds suspicious to say the least. If you were considering a product, would you "initially filter the positive and negative reviews to balance ... positive and negative reviews"?
But you might ask, "What then should we make of the cited article that clearly stated otherwise?". The answer to that goes back to another issue - scholarly research in the information age. There are now, more than ever, academic journals starving for content to collect publication fees, and to increase their brand by exploiting massive scholarly search engines. Few even have print versions, because online publishing is negligibly easy. Add insult to injury, academics are invited to peer review articles for no pay and very little oversight from editors, so the peer review process appears to be breaking. I can't speak to this article, but this is a 3 impact factor journal on Environmental Research and Public Health and the article is contributed by Chinese economics professors publishing on American pharmaceutical opinion data. I may be wrong, but if I were doing a lit review this would go in the "discard" pile for several reasons. It's been cited 33 times over 4 years. In my opinion nothing seems to fit about this. You should try to find more pertinent articles when investigating the scholarly literature.
